# Not being able to send cookies to the server for middleware

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http, axios, jwt

I needed some help regarding auth in my project, I am using SolidJS for my frontend, golang for backend and jwt for auth, I am storing jwt tokens as httpOnly cookies but those cookies won't be sent with my requests even when I turn the withCredentials flag in axios to true, I've even tried storing them as regular cookies and then making the request but as expected the cookies were not included in the request body, and the backend does have all the cors options set properly, I tested the backend using curl and it has no issues.

```
      axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user-input", {date : state.data}, { withCredentials: true }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        
      })
```